# Error while trying to push/install .apk using adb

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I've recently started encountering problems while trying to run my application from `Android Studio` on my MacOS machine. I tried to run the command from `adb` myself but I still can't get it to work, although the error appears different.

The errors I get are as follows;

**Android Studio**

> 10/02 09:54:53: Launching app $ adb push /Users/{username}/{path-to-apk}.apk /data/local/tmp/{package}
>
> java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>
> Error while Installing APK

**adb (via Terminal.app)**

> $ adb push /Users/{username}/{path-to-apk}.apk /data/local/tmp/{package}
>
> adb: error: 65536-byte write failed:
>   Undefined error: 0

Now I've tried a lot of different things, some of which are just stretches because the problem appears to lie in something adb related, but none of this seems to change anything;

- Different applications/apks
- Different Android devices (total of 5)
- Different USB-ports (all 4,
  with and without USB-hub).
- Different (or no) USB-dongles (USB-C to USB-A)
- Restart/Invalidate Caches (Android Studio)
- Reinstall Android Studio
- Reinstall Android SDK
- New (separate) install of Android SDK through homebrew
- Reset NVRAM/PRAM
- Reset SCM
- Update to MacOS Mojave (and retry all of the above).

At this point I am at a loss. Has anyone encountered these errors before without having any of the above solutions fix it? Next thing on my list is a reinstall of the OS, but that feels like a bit of overkill.

I am running on MacOS Mojave on a 2016 Macbook Pro, but everything appeared to have the same effect on High Sierra.

**Edit**

Weird update on the behaviour, I can get the installing to work continuously after a restart by doing the following steps;

- Login
- Start Terminal.app
- Manually repeat adb push command
- (Command executes successfully)
- Start Android Studio
- Everything works fine...

However, if I start Android Studio without first manually doing the adb push in Terminal, everything is broken as described above.

**Edit 2**

Even calling `adb start-server` in Terminal before starting Android Studio makes everything work. So something appears to be faulty when Android Studio is responsible for starting the adb server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but my issue appears to be solved with the latest release of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I have no idea but start-server before starting Android-studio

Comment: `adb kill-server && adb start-server` helped indeed

Answer (score 1):

Restart adb with the following command,

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server
```